# How would I inject an API service into the ModalInstanceCtrl function

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The following code is right from angular-ui getting started page: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started. I've modified it for a log in modal and would like to call the API that authorizes the user before the dialog is closed.

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  $scope.open = function (size) {
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
   templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
   controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
   size: size,
   resolve: {
  items: function () {
    return $scope.items;
  }
   }
 });

 modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
   $scope.selected = selectedItem;
 }, function () {
   $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
 });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.
```

Here is where I'd like to be able to call the service.  But I haven't been able to get the function to access anything I have that's external to it.  It seems to recognize objects (hence items), but if I inject a service into ModalDemoCtrl I'm getting an undefined error when I try to access it.

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
 item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
 $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
 $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was answered previously somewhere on Stack, but even better here is a Plunkr for a concrete example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4GcKLz?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).
service('DataService', ['$rootScope',
  function($rootScope) {
    this.data = {};
    this.data.message = 'This is a message from a service';
    this.data.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  }
]).
controller('myModal', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'DataService',
  function($scope, $modalInstance, dataService) {
    $scope.data = dataService.data;
    $scope.message = dataService.data.message;
    $scope.items = dataService.data.items;

    $scope.selected = {
      item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function() {
      $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

  }
]).
controller('appController', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'DataService',
  function($scope, $modal, $log, dataService) {

    $scope.data = dataService.data;

    $scope.showModal = function() {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'myModal'
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
      }, function() {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });

    };

  }
]);
```

HTH!